# failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref a298254a-94ff-4e45-....: "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6": not found

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils apt-transport-https && \
    apt-get install -y  lib32z1 xinetd && \
    apt-get -y dist-upgrade

RUN useradd -m ctf

WORKDIR /home/ctf

RUN cp -Rf /lib* /home/ctf && \
    cp -Rf /usr/lib* /home/ctf

COPY /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /usr/local/lib/
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/
RUN ldconfig


RUN mkdir /home/ctf/dev && \
    mknod /home/ctf/dev/null c 1 3 && \
    mknod /home/ctf/dev/zero c 1 5 && \
    mknod /home/ctf/dev/random c 1 8 && \
    mknod /home/ctf/dev/urandom c 1 9 && \
    chmod 666 /home/ctf/dev/*

RUN mkdir /home/ctf/bin && \
    cp /bin/sh /home/ctf/bin && \
    cp /bin/ls /home/ctf/bin && \
    cp /bin/cat /home/ctf/bin

COPY ./ctf.xinetd /etc/xinetd.d/ctf
COPY ./xinetedService.sh /xinetedService.sh
RUN echo "Blocked by ctf_xinetd" > /etc/banner_fail

RUN chmod +x /xinetedService.sh

COPY ./files/ /home/ctf/
RUN chown -R root:ctf /home/ctf && \
    chmod -R 750 /home/ctf && \
    chmod 740 /home/ctf/flag.txt

CMD ["/xinetedService.sh"]

EXPOSE 9999
```

The following line gives error.
`COPY /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /usr/local/lib/`

The error:

```
 => ERROR [ 6/15] COPY /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /usr/local/lib/                                                                                                                   0.0s
------
 > [ 6/15] COPY /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /usr/local/lib/:
------
Dockerfile:16
--------------------
  14 |         cp -Rf /usr/lib* /home/ctf
  15 |     
  16 | >>> COPY /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /usr/local/lib/
  17 |     ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/
  18 |     RUN ldconfig
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref a298254a-94ff-4e45-b581-67b72180e20a::opz82ic9gri5w5vumh2zpzlew: "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6": not found
```

Comment: I _did_ tell you you'd break things if you replace glibc in-place. Put one with the wrong symbol versions at a higher priority location than the one with the right versions and all the tools that came with the OS (and thus linked against its original libc version) are _expected_ to no longer work.

Comment: The advice to use a toolchain designed to be dropped into a potentially-incompatible distro, with rpaths pointing to library dependencies at known/static/non-conflicting locations, holds.

Comment: (or just, y'know, recompile the tools you want to run against the distro you intend to install them on).

Answer (score 1):

You can't `COPY` arbitrary files from the host system into an image, only files that are part of the *build context directory*; that is, the directory name you passed as the last argument to `docker build`, often the current directory `.`.

In your case you don't need this `COPY` at all.  The `ubuntu` base image already contains a dynamic loader and the rest of the normal Linux runtime.  You shouldn't need to create a shadow `/dev` tree or a separate `/home/.../bin` directory with a copy of system binaries either.

If you do have unusual needs and need to manually manipulate things like the system C library, it may also help to remember that a Docker image has an isolated filesystem.  If you, say, build GNU libc from source, the `/lib` tree in the image will be isolated from the host's and other containers' `/lib` directories.  This might be an approach to try to build a Linux image yourself `FROM scratch`; on the one hand, this is something of an expert-level project, but on the other, learning to do it in a container will keep you from making your host unusable.